# If a druid in wild shape is over healed, does it carry over to normal form?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

If the druid (in normal form) takes damage, then uses wild shape, does healing the wild shape carry over to the normal form hit points? Or does healing only affect the current form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer the first question: **No. It would not carry over due to how Wild Shape works.**

The reason: The only reason damage carries over is because you automatically revert when your HP is reduced to 0 in beast form. This means that damage is dealt after you revert technically.

> However, if you revert as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to your normal form.

Therefore the carry over of damage between forms is **delayed** damage to your caster form until you revert. **No effect of healing causes you to revert to receive the extra restoration of hitpoints lost.**

Comment: Except the feat that the class gets that lets them spend a spell slot to heal their real health when they use wildshape

Comment: That ability does not specify if it is for the druid's original form or not in the PHB. So I would disagree there as well.

Comment: It has to be his original form @D. Webber because you start with full animal health upon wildshaping, meaning healing would be pointless

Comment: Sorry I missed this notification of a reply. It does have a point, it allows for healing your beast-form in the middle of combat, as if you spent a healing spell that you currently cannot technically cast.