# If you finish a short rest while Wild Shaped, do you get both uses of Wild Shape back?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, rests

Let's say you're a level 8 druid, so you have 4 hours per use of *Wildshape*.
Now, at 11:00, you expend one use of it to turn yourself into a *Raven* (or any other beast).
From 12:00 to 13:00, you take a rest, while still being in your raven form ([which works](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71229/can-a-wild-shaped-druid-regain-hit-points-after-a-short-rest)).

Obviously, you can stay in raven form until 15:00, at which point you revert to your regular form.

Then, from 13:00 to 15:00, you are in raven form. The PHB states on *Wildshape*:

> You can use this feature twice. You regain expended uses when you finish a short or long rest.

You just finished a short rest, meaning you would still be transformed *and* get both uses back (assuming you expend your use of *Wildshape* when you transform, not when you end it, which would make this question irrelevant). This might not be a balancing issue if you're a CR0 raven, but it might very well be relevant for other *Wildshapes*.

Hence my question:

## If you finish a short rest while *Wildshaped*, do you get both uses back and can therefore "overstock" your total maximum *Wildshape* time per rest?

Or would you simply auto-expend one use, and reset the timer on that use?